# iOS 8 auto layout? Do I need it?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

Is there a way to have an app work on all tall iPhone devices (portrait mode) without using Auto Layout?

Can I just design for say iPhone 5 and have iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus stretch to fill.

Auto layout seems overkill when I don't need to design for landscape or iPad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even if I were building an app only for one iphone size, I would use auto layout. It helps in so many ways besides just supporting various screen sizes. One man's opinion. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @MikeTaverne. Usage of AutoLayout gives you lots of benefits.

Comment: @GeorgeYacoub do you have more questions? otherwise could you tick the green checkmark for any of the answers?

Comment: I didn't down vote your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Auto layout seems overkill when I don't need to design for landscape
>   or iPad.

That's definitely *not* true. You could argue it was true before the launch of the iPhone 6, but even with only iPhones 4 and 5 it helps to account for different situations.

> Can I just design for say iPhone 5 and have iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus
>   stretch to fill.

*Stretch to fill* is something that you can easily achieve with AutoLayout.

I know it seems a bit tough at first, but it's actually based on really simple mechanisms and behaves very logically. It's definetely worth giving it a try, you'll get much more out of it than you might expect right not.

Answer (score 1):

Although Auto layout is optional, but to me it is a recommended feature.

Once your design become complex, you would have to write a lot of code to support different screen sizes. This can be avoided by using auto-layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can in Show the size inspector-> Autoresizing. But you have to do it for each subview for each .xib file or in storyboard